# Ignite cache fails after Failed to process selector key...java.io.IOException: Broken pipe exception

Tags: ignite, gridgain

We are running Ignite 2.4 & have 2 server nodes & 30 odd client nodes. We use zookeeper discovery & the nodes are deployed in a Docker swarm environment.

After a while of running i saw the below exception in one of the ignite clients & the caches no longer seem to work,

```
service-be - [INFO ] 2018-06-15 02:01:52.256 [grid-timeout-worker-#55] org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal -
Metrics for local node (to disable set 'metricsLogFrequency' to 0)
    ^-- Node [id=5249f20c, uptime=02:49:02.178]
    ^-- H/N/C [hosts=34, nodes=34, CPUs=816]
    ^-- CPU [cur=24.2%, avg=0.27%, GC=0%]
    ^-- PageMemory [pages=0]
    ^-- Heap [used=848MB, free=17.19%, comm=1024MB]
    ^-- Non heap [used=241MB, free=84.12%, comm=251MB]
    ^-- Outbound messages queue [size=4]
    ^-- Public thread pool [active=0, idle=0, qSize=0]
    ^-- System thread pool [active=0, idle=24, qSize=0]
service-be - [INFO ] 2018-06-15 02:01:52.432 [grid-nio-worker-tcp-comm-2-#59] org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi - Accepted incoming communication connection [locAddr=/10.11.0.7:47100, rmtAddr=/10.11.0.75:59204]
service-be - [INFO ] 2018-06-15 02:01:52.433 [grid-nio-worker-tcp-comm-2-#59] org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi - Received incoming connection when already connected to this node, rejecting [locNode=5249f20c-456b-4b6f-ab41-f5cd5c3c05ba, rmtNode=6739c9af-42d1-4aad-ac9c-ac738ed13534]
service-be - [INFO ] 2018-06-15 02:01:52.634 [grid-nio-worker-tcp-comm-3-#60] org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi - Accepted incoming communication connection [locAddr=/10.11.0.7:47100, rmtAddr=/10.11.0.75:59206]
service-be - [INFO ] 2018-06-15 02:01:52.635 [grid-nio-worker-tcp-comm-3-#60] org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi - Received incoming connection when already connected to this node, rejecting [locNode=5249f20c-456b-4b6f-ab41-f5cd5c3c05ba, rmtNode=6739c9af-42d1-4aad-ac9c-ac738ed13534]
service-be - [INFO ] 2018-06-15 02:01:52.836 [grid-nio-worker-tcp-comm-4-#61] org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi - Accepted incoming communication connection [locAddr=/10.11.0.7:47100, rmtAddr=/10.11.0.75:59208]
service-be - [INFO ] 2018-06-15 02:01:52.837 [grid-nio-worker-tcp-comm-4-#61] org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi - Received incoming connection when already connected to this node, rejecting [locNode=5249f20c-456b-4b6f-ab41-f5cd5c3c05ba, rmtNode=6739c9af-42d1-4aad-ac9c-ac738ed13534]
service-be - [INFO ] 2018-06-15 02:01:53.038 [grid-nio-worker-tcp-comm-5-#62] org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi - Accepted incoming communication connection [locAddr=/10.11.0.7:47100, rmtAddr=/10.11.0.75:59210]
service-be - [INFO ] 2018-06-15 02:01:53.039 [grid-nio-worker-tcp-comm-5-#62] org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi - Received incoming connection when already connected to this node, rejecting [locNode=5249f20c-456b-4b6f-ab41-f5cd5c3c05ba, rmtNode=6739c9af-42d1-4aad-ac9c-ac738ed13534]
service-be - [ERROR] 2018-06-15 02:01:53.231 [grid-nio-worker-tcp-comm-0-#57] org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi - Failed to process selector key [ses=GridSelectorNioSessionImpl [worker=DirectNioClientWorker [super=AbstractNioClientWorker [idx=0, bytesRcvd=70700138, bytesSent=18478193, bytesRcvd0=0, bytesSent0=0, select=true, super=GridWorker [name=grid-nio-worker-tcp-comm-0, igniteInstanceName=null, finished=false, hashCode=30436088, interrupted=false, runner=grid-nio-worker-tcp-comm-0-#57]]], writeBuf=java.nio.DirectByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=186 cap=32768], readBuf=java.nio.DirectByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=32768 cap=32768], inRecovery=GridNioRecoveryDescriptor [acked=48224, resendCnt=0, rcvCnt=111504, sentCnt=48229, reserved=true, lastAck=111488, nodeLeft=false, node=TcpDiscoveryNode [id=6739c9af-42d1-4aad-ac9c-ac738ed13534, addrs=[10.11.0.74, 10.11.0.75, 127.0.0.1, 172.18.0.22], sockAddrs=[/172.18.0.22:47500, bdd554c3dc77/10.11.0.75:47500, /10.11.0.74:47500, /127.0.0.1:47500], discPort=47500, order=1, intOrder=1, lastExchangeTime=1529039549468, loc=false, ver=2.4.0#20180305-sha1:aa342270, isClient=false], connected=false, connectCnt=1, queueLimit=131072, reserveCnt=2, pairedConnections=false], outRecovery=GridNioRecoveryDescriptor [acked=48224, resendCnt=0, rcvCnt=111504, sentCnt=48229, reserved=true, lastAck=111488, nodeLeft=false, node=TcpDiscoveryNode [id=6739c9af-42d1-4aad-ac9c-ac738ed13534, addrs=[10.11.0.74, 10.11.0.75, 127.0.0.1, 172.18.0.22], sockAddrs=[/172.18.0.22:47500, bdd554c3dc77/10.11.0.75:47500, /10.11.0.74:47500, /127.0.0.1:47500], discPort=47500, order=1, intOrder=1, lastExchangeTime=1529039549468, loc=false, ver=2.4.0#20180305-sha1:aa342270, isClient=false], connected=false, connectCnt=1, queueLimit=131072, reserveCnt=2, pairedConnections=false], super=GridNioSessionImpl [locAddr=/10.11.0.7:42970, rmtAddr=bdd554c3dc77/10.11.0.75:47100, createTime=1529039561958, closeTime=0, bytesSent=18478193, bytesRcvd=70700138, bytesSent0=0, bytesRcvd0=0, sndSchedTime=1529044007457, lastSndTime=1529049712225, lastRcvTime=1529049712225, readsPaused=false, filterChain=FilterChain[filters=[GridNioCodecFilter [parser=o.a.i.i.util.nio.GridDirectParser@7a15b36, directMode=true], GridConnectionBytesVerifyFilter], accepted=false]]]
java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
        at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.write0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDispatcher.java:47)
        at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:93)
        at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:51)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:471)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioServer$DirectNioClientWorker.processWrite0(GridNioServer.java:1636)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioServer$DirectNioClientWorker.processWrite(GridNioServer.java:1293)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioServer$AbstractNioClientWorker.processSelectedKeysOptimized(GridNioServer.java:2307)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioServer$AbstractNioClientWorker.bodyInternal(GridNioServer.java:2080)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioServer$AbstractNioClientWorker.body(GridNioServer.java:1749)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.worker.GridWorker.run(GridWorker.java:110)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
service-be - [WARN ] 2018-06-15 02:01:53.231 [grid-nio-worker-tcp-comm-0-#57] org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi - Closing NIO session because of unhandled exception [cls=class o.a.i.i.util.nio.GridNioException, msg=Broken pipe]
service-be - [INFO ] 2018-06-15 02:01:53.240 [grid-nio-worker-tcp-comm-6-#63] org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi - Accepted incoming communication connection [locAddr=/10.11.0.7:47100, rmtAddr=/10.11.0.75:59212]
service-be - [WARN ] 2018-06-15 02:02:03.253 [tcp-comm-worker-#1] org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi - Connect timed out (consider increasing 'failureDetectionTimeout' configuration property) [addr=/172.18.0.22:47100, failureDetectionTimeout=10000]
```

On searching with the remote node with which there seems to be trouble connecting (as mentioned in the trace above) I also see these warnings in some of the other client nodes aswell.

Any obvious pointers on what could be going wrong?. From what i have searched one suggestion was to use ipv4 but the docker overlay has enableipv6 as disabled in our case..so i am not sure how much that will help.

```
[root@rhel743411 logs]# egrep -i "6739c9af-42d1-4aad-ac9c-ac738ed13534" *
service1-mw.log:service1-mw - [WARN ] 2018-06-16 00:27:55.884 [grid-timeout-worker-#55] org.apache.ignite.internal.diagnostic - Found long running cache future [startTime=00:26:02.991, curTime=00:27:55.876, fut=GridDhtColocatedLockFuture [threadId=39579, keys=[UserKeyCacheObjectImpl [part=8, val=8, hasValBytes=false]], futId=776a8520461-6a403605-a8fd-4ed1-bd45-92e648929a2a, lockVer=GridCacheVersion [topVer=140519300, order=1529059257539, nodeOrder=6], read=false, retval=true, err=null, timeout=120000, topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=34, minorTopVer=0], done=0, trackable=true, createTtl=-1, accessTtl=-1, skipStore=false, keepBinary=false, recovery=false, miniId=1, topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=34, minorTopVer=0], innerFuts=[[node=6739c9af-42d1-4aad-ac9c-ac738ed13534, rcvRes=false, loc=false, done=false]], inTx=false, super=GridCompoundIdentityFuture [super=GridCompoundFuture [rdc=Bool reducer: true, initFlag=1, lsnrCalls=0, done=false, cancelled=false, err=null, futs=[false]]]]]
service1-mw.log:service1-mw - [WARN ] 2018-06-16 00:27:55.884 [grid-timeout-worker-#55] org.apache.ignite.internal.diagnostic - Found long running cache future [startTime=00:25:55.893, curTime=00:27:55.876, fut=GridDhtColocatedLockFuture [threadId=297, keys=[UserKeyCacheObjectImpl [part=8, val=8, hasValBytes=false]], futId=f03a8520461-6a403605-a8fd-4ed1-bd45-92e648929a2a, lockVer=GridCacheVersion [topVer=140519300, order=1529059253553, nodeOrder=6], read=false, retval=true, err=null, timeout=120000, topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=34, minorTopVer=0], done=0, trackable=true, createTtl=-1, accessTtl=-1, skipStore=false, keepBinary=false, recovery=false, miniId=1, topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=34, minorTopVer=0], innerFuts=[[node=6739c9af-42d1-4aad-ac9c-ac738ed13534, rcvRes=false, loc=false, done=false]], inTx=false, super=GridCompoundIdentityFuture [super=GridCompoundFuture [rdc=Bool reducer: true, initFlag=1, lsnrCalls=0, done=false, cancelled=false, err=null, futs=[false]]]]]
service1-mw.log:service1-mw - [WARN ] 2018-06-16 00:27:55.884 [grid-timeout-worker-#55] org.apache.ignite.internal.diagnostic - Found long running cache future [startTime=00:26:51.661, curTime=00:27:55.876, fut=GridDhtColocatedLockFuture [threadId=38749, keys=[UserKeyCacheObjectImpl [part=7, val=7, hasValBytes=false], UserKeyCacheObjectImpl [part=8, val=8, hasValBytes=false]], futId=354b8520461-6a403605-a8fd-4ed1-bd45-92e648929a2a, lockVer=GridCacheVersion [topVer=140519300, order=1529059268380, nodeOrder=6], read=false, retval=true, err=null, timeout=120000, topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=34, minorTopVer=0], done=0, trackable=true, createTtl=-1, accessTtl=-1, skipStore=false, keepBinary=false, recovery=false, miniId=1, topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=34, minorTopVer=0], innerFuts=[[node=6739c9af-42d1-4aad-ac9c-ac738ed13534, rcvRes=false, loc=false, done=false]], inTx=false, super=GridCompoundIdentityFuture [super=GridCompoundFuture [rdc=Bool reducer: true, initFlag=1, lsnrCalls=0, done=false, cancelled=false, err=null, futs=[false]]]]]
service1-mw.log:service1-mw - [WARN ] 2018-06-16 00:27:55.885 [grid-timeout-worker-#55] org.apache.ignite.internal.diagnostic - Found long running cache future [startTime=00:26:51.772, curTime=00:27:55.876, fut=GridDhtColocatedLockFuture [threadId=343, keys=[UserKeyCacheObjectImpl [part=7, val=7, hasValBytes=false]], futId=125b8520461-6a403605-a8fd-4ed1-bd45-92e648929a2a, lockVer=GridCacheVersion [topVer=140519300, order=1529059268816, nodeOrder=6], read=false, retval=true, err=null, timeout=120000, topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=34, minorTopVer=0], done=0, trackable=true, createTtl=-1, accessTtl=-1, skipStore=false, keepBinary=false, recovery=false, miniId=1, topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=34, minorTopVer=0], innerFuts=[[node=6739c9af-42d1-4aad-ac9c-ac738ed13534, rcvRes=false, loc=false, done=false]], inTx=false, super=GridCompoundIdentityFuture [super=GridCompoundFuture [rdc=Bool reducer: true, initFlag=1, lsnrCalls=0, done=false, cancelled=false, err=null, futs=[false]]]]]
service2-mw.log:service2y-mw - [WARN ] 2018-06-16 00:01:10.227 [grid-timeout-worker-#55] org.apache.ignite.internal.diagnostic - Found long running cache future [startTime=23:59:12.637, curTime=00:01:10.221, fut=GridDhtColocatedLockFuture [threadId=21129, keys=[UserKeyCacheObjectImpl [part=8, val=8, hasValBytes=false]], futId=f5216120461-0c4dcfda-c90b-42a3-83c4-8d2f8ecb6ab1, lockVer=GridCacheVersion [topVer=140519300, order=1529058842000, nodeOrder=17], read=false, retval=true, err=null, timeout=120000, topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=34, minorTopVer=0], done=0, trackable=true, createTtl=-1, accessTtl=-1, skipStore=false, keepBinary=false, recovery=false, miniId=1, topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=34, minorTopVer=0], innerFuts=[[node=6739c9af-42d1-4aad-ac9c-ac738ed13534, rcvRes=false, loc=false, done=false]], inTx=false, super=GridCompoundIdentityFuture [super=GridCompoundFuture [rdc=Bool reducer: true, initFlag=1, lsnrCalls=0, done=false, cancelled=false, err=null, futs=[false]]]]]
service2-mw.log:service2y-mw - [WARN ] 2018-06-16 00:09:10.242 [grid-timeout-worker-#55] org.apache.ignite.internal.diagnostic - Found long running cache future [startTime=00:07:30.520, curTime=00:09:10.239, fut=GridDhtColocatedLockFuture [threadId=21304, keys=[UserKeyCacheObjectImpl [part=8, val=8, hasValBytes=false]], futId=42176120461-0c4dcfda-c90b-42a3-83c4-8d2f8ecb6ab1, lockVer=GridCacheVersion [topVer=140519300, order=1529058982457, nodeOrder=17], read=false, retval=true, err=null, timeout=120000, topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=34, minorTopVer=0], done=0, trackable=true, createTtl=-1, accessTtl=-1, skipStore=false, keepBinary=false, recovery=false, miniId=1, topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=34, minorTopVer=0], innerFuts=[[node=6739c9af-42d1-4aad-ac9c-ac738ed13534, rcvRes=false, loc=false, done=false]], inTx=false, super=GridCompoundIdentityFuture [super=GridCompoundFuture [rdc=Bool reducer: true, initFlag=1, lsnrCalls=0, done=false, cancelled=false, err=null, futs=[false]]]]]
service2-mw.log:service2y-mw - [WARN ] 2018-06-16 00:13:10.269 [grid-timeout-worker-#55] org.apache.ignite.internal.diagnostic - Found long running cache future [startTime=00:11:32.462, curTime=00:13:10.268, fut=GridDhtColocatedLockFuture [threadId=21368, keys=[UserKeyCacheObjectImpl [part=7, val=7, hasValBytes=false]], futId=c0f96120461-0c4dcfda-c90b-42a3-83c4-8d2f8ecb6ab1, lockVer=GridCacheVersion [topVer=140519300, order=1529059041395, nodeOrder=17], read=false, retval=true, err=null, timeout=120000, topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=34, minorTopVer=0], done=0, trackable=true, createTtl=-1, accessTtl=-1, skipStore=false, keepBinary=false, recovery=false, miniId=1, topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=34, minorTopVer=0], innerFuts=[[node=6739c9af-42d1-4aad-ac9c-ac738ed13534, rcvRes=false, loc=false, done=false]], inTx=false, super=GridCompoundIdentityFuture [super=GridCompoundFuture [rdc=Bool reducer: true, initFlag=1, lsnrCalls=0, done=false, cancelled=false, err=null, futs=[false]]]]]
service2-mw.log:service2y-mw - [WARN ] 2018-06-16 00:15:10.281 [grid-timeout-worker-#55] org.apache.ignite.internal.diagnostic - Found long running cache future [startTime=00:13:43.800, curTime=00:15:10.279, fut=GridDhtColocatedLockFuture [threadId=172, keys=[UserKeyCacheObjectImpl [part=7, val=7, hasValBytes=false], UserKeyCacheObjectImpl [part=8, val=8, hasValBytes=false]], futId=49ab6120461-0c4dcfda-c90b-42a3-83c4-8d2f8ecb6ab1, lockVer=GridCacheVersion [topVer=140519300, order=1529059079186, nodeOrder=17], read=false, retval=true, err=null, timeout=120000, topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=34, minorTopVer=0], done=0, trackable=true, createTtl=-1, accessTtl=-1, skipStore=false, keepBinary=false, recovery=false, miniId=1, topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=34, minorTopVer=0], innerFuts=[[node=6739c9af-42d1-4aad-ac9c-ac738ed13534, rcvRes=false, loc=false, done=false]], inTx=false, super=GridCompoundIdentityFuture [super=GridCompoundFuture [rdc=Bool reducer: true, initFlag=1, lsnrCalls=0, done=false, cancelled=false, err=null, futs=[false]]]]]
service2-mw.log:service2y-mw - [WARN ] 2018-06-16 00:17:10.289 [grid-timeout-worker-#55] org.apache.ignite.internal.diagnostic - Found long running cache future [startTime=00:15:44.860, curTime=00:17:10.287, fut=GridDhtColocatedLockFuture [threadId=172, keys=[UserKeyCacheObjectImpl [part=8, val=8, hasValBytes=false]], futId=a3ec6120461-0c4dcfda-c90b-42a3-83c4-8d2f8ecb6ab1, lockVer=GridCacheVersion [topVer=140519300, order=1529059106786, nodeOrder=17], read=false, retval=true, err=null, timeout=120000, topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=34, minorTopVer=0], done=0, trackable=true, createTtl=-1, accessTtl=-1, skipStore=false, keepBinary=false, recovery=false, miniId=1, topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=34, minorTopVer=0], innerFuts=[[node=6739c9af-42d1-4aad-ac9c-ac738ed13534, rcvRes=false, loc=false, done=false]], inTx=false, super=GridCompoundIdentityFuture [super=GridCompoundFuture [rdc=Bool reducer: true, initFlag=1, lsnrCalls=0, done=false, cancelled=false, err=null, futs=[false]]]]]
service2-mw.log:service2y-mw - [WARN ] 2018-06-16 00:20:10.299 [grid-timeout-worker-#55] org.apache.ignite.internal.diagnostic - Found long running cache future [startTime=00:18:51.741, curTime=00:20:10.298, fut=GridDhtColocatedLockFuture [threadId=172, keys=[UserKeyCacheObjectImpl [part=7, val=7, hasValBytes=false], UserKeyCacheObjectImpl [part=8, val=8, hasValBytes=false]], futId=8ace6120461-0c4dcfda-c90b-42a3-83c4-8d2f8ecb6ab1, lockVer=GridCacheVersion [topVer=140519300, order=1529059136637, nodeOrder=17], read=false, retval=true, err=null, timeout=120000, topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=34, minorTopVer=0], done=0, trackable=true, createTtl=-1, accessTtl=-1, skipStore=false, keepBinary=false, recovery=false, miniId=1, topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=34, minorTopVer=0], innerFuts=[[node=6739c9af-42d1-4aad-ac9c-ac738ed13534, rcvRes=false, loc=false, done=false]], inTx=false, super=GridCompoundIdentityFuture [super=GridCompoundFuture [rdc=Bool reducer: true, initFlag=1, lsnrCalls=0, done=false, cancelled=false, err=null, futs=[false]]]]]
service2-mw.log:service2y-mw - [WARN ] 2018-06-16 00:21:10.308 [grid-timeout-worker-#55] org.apache.ignite.internal.diagnostic - Found long running cache future [startTime=00:19:19.018, curTime=00:21:10.304, fut=GridDhtColocatedLockFuture [threadId=21484, keys=[UserKeyCacheObjectImpl [part=8, val=8, hasValBytes=false]], futId=bd7f6120461-0c4dcfda-c90b-42a3-83c4-8d2f8ecb6ab1, lockVer=GridCacheVersion [topVer=140519300, order=1529059155514, nodeOrder=17], read=false, retval=true, err=null, timeout=120000, topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=34, minorTopVer=0], done=0, trackable=true, createTtl=-1, accessTtl=-1, skipStore=false, keepBinary=false, recovery=false, miniId=1, topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=34, minorTopVer=0], innerFuts=[[node=6739c9af-42d1-4aad-ac9c-ac738ed13534, rcvRes=false, loc=false, done=false]], inTx=false, super=GridCompoundIdentityFuture [super=GridCompoundFuture [rdc=Bool reducer: true, initFlag=1, lsnrCalls=0, done=false, cancelled=false, err=null, futs=[false]]]]]
service2-mw.log:service2y-mw - [WARN ] 2018-06-16 00:24:10.326 [grid-timeout-worker-#55] org.apache.ignite.internal.diagnostic - Found long running cache future [startTime=00:23:03.860, curTime=00:24:10.323, fut=GridDhtColocatedLockFuture [threadId=21544, keys=[UserKeyCacheObjectImpl [part=7, val=7, hasValBytes=false]], futId=f3e17120461-0c4dcfda-c90b-42a3-83c4-8d2f8ecb6ab1, lockVer=GridCacheVersion [topVer=140519300, order=1529059200701, nodeOrder=17], read=false, retval=true, err=null, timeout=120000, topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=34, minorTopVer=0], done=0, trackable=true, createTtl=-1, accessTtl=-1, skipStore=false, keepBinary=false, recovery=false, miniId=1, topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=34, minorTopVer=0], innerFuts=[[node=6739c9af-42d1-4aad-ac9c-ac738ed13534, rcvRes=false, loc=false, done=false]], inTx=false, super=GridCompoundIdentityFuture [super=GridCompoundFuture [rdc=Bool reducer: true, initFlag=1, lsnrCalls=0, done=false, cancelled=false, err=null, futs=[false]]]]]
service2-mw.log:service2y-mw - [WARN ] 2018-06-16 00:24:10.326 [grid-timeout-worker-#55] org.apache.ignite.internal.diagnostic - Found long running cache future [startTime=00:22:52.783, curTime=00:24:10.323, fut=GridDhtColocatedLockFuture [threadId=172, keys=[UserKeyCacheObjectImpl [part=7, val=7, hasValBytes=false], UserKeyCacheObjectImpl [part=8, val=8, hasValBytes=false]], futId=edc17120461-0c4dcfda-c90b-42a3-83c4-8d2f8ecb6ab1, lockVer=GridCacheVersion [topVer=140519300, order=1529059199113, nodeOrder=17], read=false, retval=true, err=null, timeout=120000, topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=34, minorTopVer=0], done=0, trackable=true, createTtl=-1, accessTtl=-1, skipStore=false, keepBinary=false, recovery=false, miniId=1, topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=34, minorTopVer=0], innerFuts=[[node=6739c9af-42d1-4aad-ac9c-ac738ed13534, rcvRes=false, loc=false, done=false]], inTx=false, super=GridCompoundIdentityFuture [super=GridCompoundFuture [rdc=Bool reducer: true, initFlag=1, lsnrCalls=0, done=false, cancelled=false, err=null, futs=[false]]]]]
service2-mw.log:service2y-mw - [WARN ] 2018-06-16 00:26:10.330 [grid-timeout-worker-#55] org.apache.ignite.internal.diagnostic - Found long running cache future [startTime=00:24:59.321, curTime=00:26:10.328, fut=GridDhtColocatedLockFuture [threadId=172, keys=[UserKeyCacheObjectImpl [part=7, val=7, hasValBytes=false]], futId=74737120461-0c4dcfda-c90b-42a3-83c4-8d2f8ecb6ab1, lockVer=GridCacheVersion [topVer=140519300, order=1529059232146, nodeOrder=17], read=false, retval=true, err=null, timeout=120000, topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=34, minorTopVer=0], done=0, trackable=true, createTtl=-1, accessTtl=-1, skipStore=false, keepBinary=false, recovery=false, miniId=1, topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=34, minorTopVer=0], innerFuts=[[node=6739c9af-42d1-4aad-ac9c-ac738ed13534, rcvRes=false, loc=false, done=false]], inTx=false, super=GridCompoundIdentityFuture [super=GridCompoundFuture [rdc=Bool reducer: true, initFlag=1, lsnrCalls=0, done=false, cancelled=false, err=null, futs=[false]]]]]
service2-mw.log:service2y-mw - [WARN ] 2018-06-16 00:29:10.349 [grid-timeout-worker-#55] org.apache.ignite.internal.diagnostic - Found long running cache future [startTime=00:27:32.480, curTime=00:29:10.347, fut=GridDhtColocatedLockFuture [threadId=21621, keys=[UserKeyCacheObjectImpl [part=8, val=8, hasValBytes=false]], futId=1fe57120461-0c4dcfda-c90b-42a3-83c4-8d2f8ecb6ab1, lockVer=GridCacheVersion [topVer=140519300, order=1529059289421, nodeOrder=17], read=false, retval=true, err=null, timeout=120000, topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=34, minorTopVer=0], done=0, trackable=true, createTtl=-1, accessTtl=-1, skipStore=false, keepBinary=false, recovery=false, miniId=1, topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=34, minorTopVer=0], innerFuts=[[node=6739c9af-42d1-4aad-ac9c-ac738ed13534, rcvRes=false, loc=false, done=false]], inTx=false, super=GridCompoundIdentityFuture [super=GridCompoundFuture [rdc=Bool reducer: true, initFlag=1, lsnrCalls=0, done=false, cancelled=false, err=null, futs=[false]]]]]
```

Comment: I suspect it has something to do with inconsistent network configuration. Could you please share your nodes configuration files? Also you can go ahead and try increasing failureDetectionTimeout and clientFailureDetectionTimeout (at this stage better to set both to the same value, like 60000).

Comment: Also please share full logs from servers and from a couple of clients (I assume all clients have similar logs, right?)